# Headphones with 3 wires: blue, green, and copper

Tags: headphones

I'm trying to replace the male connector on my headphones. After cutting off the broken connector, there are three little wires sticking out, colored green, blue, and copper. What does each color correspond to? As far as I can tell, nobody else seems to have had this issue.

Comment: Use an ohmmeter to work out which goes to which ring/tip at the jack end. That will let us tell you.

Comment: Upload a picture with a clear view

Answer (score 2):

In some headphones, the blue is Common, green is Left channel, and gold(copper) is Right channel.

It is however hard to confirm this without the headphones model.

Answer (score 1):

The colours are a bit weird, but the bare copper is usually ground, green and blue would be your left and right channels.

Convention is that red is usually the right channel and green or blue the left channel, so you need to either just try wiring it up and see if you got it right, or measure your old connector with a multimeter in conductivity test mode to figure out which wire leads to which conductor on the old TRS-plug.

As for the wiring, here's the schematic, Tip is Left, Ring is Right and the Sleeve is Ground:

[image]